# Wrapping a command that includes single and double quotes for another command

Tags: shell, zsh, quoting

I recently learned about [watch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watch_%28Unix%29), but am having trouble making it work with relatively sophisticated commands.

For example, I would like to ask `watch` to run the following command on `zsh` every three seconds<sup>*</sup>:

```
for x in `command_1 | grep keyword | cut -d' ' -f1`; do command_2 "word[word=number]" $x; done
```

as you can see the line above includes single quotes, double quotes, among other special characters.

So I tried:

```
watch -n 3 "for x in `my_command | grep keyword | cut -d' ' -f1`; do command2 "rusage[mem=7000]" $x; done"
```

but then I got:

> no matches found for x in !@#$# ....; done

I tried other combinations without success. Here's one of those attempts:

```
watch -n 3 "for x in $(bjobs -w | grep pre_seg | cut -d' ' -f1); do bmod -R "rusage[mem=7000]" $x; done"
```

which also results in a similar error.

Any ideas how to make this work?

---

<sup>*</sup>I would also be intersted in solutions that work on `bash`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

General tip: if you have two levels of nesting, avoid using single quotes in the inner command, and use single quotes around the outer command.

Additional tip: don't use backticks - `` `…` ``  - to execute code, instead use `$(…)` around it. Dollar-parentheses is pretty much DWIM('Do what I mean') when it comes to nested quotes; backquotes have arcane, shell-dependent rules.

```
watch -n 3 'for x in $(my_command | grep keyword | cut -d" " -f1); do command2 "rusage[mem=7000]" "$x"; done'
```

If you need single quotes inside a single-quoted command, you can use `'\''`. Think of these four characters as the way to quote a single quote inside single quotes, though technically speaking this is constructed as end the single-quoted string, append a literal single quote, and start a new single-quoted string (still appended to the current word).

For more complex cases, either painstakingly count the quotes, or define temporary variables.

```
cmd='for x in $(my_command | grep keyword | cut -d" " -f1); do command2 "rusage[mem=7000]" "$x"; done'
watch_cmd='watch -n 3 "$cmd"'
```

This answer isn't specific to zsh. Zsh doesn't bring anything major here. You can save a bit of quoting because there's no need for double quotes around command substitutions, and sometimes there are ways to use built-ins rather than external commands which reduce the quoting needs, but the underlying issues are the same as in other shells.

Oh, and by the way, note that `watch` will execute your command in `sh`, not in zsh. If you want to execute the command in zsh, you need to run

```
watch -n 3 -x zsh -c "$cmd"
```

on Debian/Ubuntu, and

```
export cmd
watch -n 3 'exec zsh -c "$cmd"'
```

(even more quoting!) elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. That was very helpful. Interestingly `watch` does not come with the `-x` nor `-c` options on my machine. I looked it up online and haven't found any man pages that mention them. What do these options do?

Comment: @intrpc `-x` tells `watch` not to pass the command through a shell. I just found out that this is specific to Debian/Ubuntu, even though it's not indicated as such. The `-c` is passed to `zsh`, not to `watch`.

Comment: @Gilles The `-x` and `-exec` options both exist in my `watch` (on gentoo), so this is definitely not Debian-specific. Maybe you compared with some other version of `watch`? Mine comes from [procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) package.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz `watch` comes from `procps` on Debian too. The [official source](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/watch.c?revision=1.16&view=markup) doesn't have `--exec`. The package in Debian (and derivatives including Ubuntu) adds the option in a Debian-specific patch (`watch_exec_beep.patch`; it's “Mortys watch exec patch” from [bug #410967](http://bugs.debian.org/183346)). Gentoo may have adopted a similar patch.

Comment: This was the key part for me!: "If you need single quotes inside a single-quoted command, you can use `'\''`. Think of these four characters as the way to quote a single quote inside single quotes, though technically speaking this is constructed as end the single-quoted string, append a literal single quote, and start a new single-quoted string (still appended to the current word)."