# Why doesn't the following work?: while true; do "$my_command"; sleep 1; done

Tags: shell-script, zsh

Following up on the top answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23347/wrapping-a-command-that-includes-single-and-double-quotes-for-another-command), I thought I could:

1)  Define a command:

```
cmd='for x in $(my_command | grep keyword | cut -d" " -f1); do command2 "arguments" $x; done'
```

2) Run it on a loop as follows

```
while true; do "$cmd"; sleep 1; done
```

However, the above doesn't work, and I get the following

```
zsh: command not found for x in $(......
zsh: command not found for x in $(......
zsh: command not found for x in $(......
...
```

Any thoughts why?

#### Clarification:

If I run `for x in $(my_command | grep keyword | cut -d" " -f1); do command2 "arguments" $x; done'` it works perfectly.

#### Addendum:

I have noticed that if I use `eval`, it works, i.e.:

```
while true; do eval "$cmd"; sleep 1; done
```

runs the command `cmd` every second

Comment: Does `zsh` have the same for construct?

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, I'll clarify that `eval "$cmd"` or just running the contents of `cmd` work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By putting quotes around `$cmd`, you're asking the shell to run a command named exactly that. There is not command named "for x in $(..."; in fact on my system, there isn't even a command named "for" - it's a shell keyword. To run the contents of `$cmd`, you'll have to use `eval`.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn. Hhmm, but why does the above syntax work for `watch` then? (see the link to a related question at the beginning of the OP)

Comment: Nevermind, I think that @Guilles explained that in the `watch` example `"$cmd"` is passsed as an **argument** to bash, which I guess explains why it does not need `eval`

Comment: It is because the shell is expecting a string, which it interprets line-by-line; just as it would when running a script from a file.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to prepare a command for running inside the same shell, use a function.

```
cmd () {
  for x in $(my_command | grep keyword | cut -d" " -f1); do
    command2 "arguments" $x
  done
}
while true; do cmd; sleep 1; done
```