# How to alias a command with '

Tags: zsh, quoting, alias

I wanted to make an alias turn caps lock off:

```
python -c 'from ctypes import *; X11 = cdll.LoadLibrary("libX11.so.6"); display = X11.XOpenDisplay(None); X11.XkbLockModifiers(display, c_uint(0x0100), c_uint(2), c_uint(0)); X11.XCloseDisplay(display)'
```

I wrote this into my .zshrc:

```
alias caps='python -c 'from ctypes import *; X11 = cdll.LoadLibrary("libX11.so.6"); display = X11.XOpenDisplay(None); X11.XkbLockModifiers(display, c_uint(0x0100), c_uint(2), c_uint(0)); X11.XCloseDisplay(display)' '
```

But it seems that the problem is that I have `'` in the command (so it make an alias to a part of it).

I tried to use:

```
alias caps=" python -c 'from ctypes import *; X11 = cdll.LoadLibrary("libX11.so.6"); display = X11.XOpenDisplay(None); X11.XkbLockModifiers(display, c_uint(0x0100), c_uint(2), c_uint(0)); X11.XCloseDisplay(display)' "
```

to see if something changed and I get python's sintax error.

So how can I make an alias to a one-liner with `'` inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes in the python script:

```
alias caps="python -c 'from ctypes import *; X11 = cdll.LoadLibrary(\"libX11.so.6\"); display = X11.XOpenDisplay(None); X11.XkbLockModifiers(display, c_uint(0x0100), c_uint(2), c_uint(0)); X11.XCloseDisplay(display)' "
```

Of course, you could also save that as a python script, and then

```
alias caps='path/to/script.py'
```

Comment: Thanks! I considered using a script but wanted to know the other way.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the easy way to quote a string (such as a shell command) that can contain arbitrary characters is:

- Replace all single quotes `'` in the string by the 4-character sequence `'\''`.
- Put single quotes `'…'` around the string.

See [Wrapping a command that includes single and double quotes for another command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23347/wrapping-a-command-that-includes-single-and-double-quotes-for-another-command/23349#23349) for more details.

Thus (with an optimization on the last character which happens to be a single quote):

```
alias caps='python -c '\''from ctypes import *; X11 = cdll.LoadLibrary("libX11.so.6"); display = X11.XOpenDisplay(None); X11.XkbLockModifiers(display, c_uint(0x0100), c_uint(2), c_uint(0)); X11.XCloseDisplay(display)'\'
```

However, rather than dwell into such complexities, just make it a function.

```
caps () {
  python -c 'from ctypes import *; X11 = cdll.LoadLibrary("libX11.so.6"); display = X11.XOpenDisplay(None); X11.XkbLockModifiers(display, c_uint(0x0100), c_uint(2), c_uint(0)); X11.XCloseDisplay(display)'
}
```

Or make it a [script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80254/how-do-i-turn-off-caps-lock-the-lock-not-the-key-by-command-line/80301#80301).

Answer (score 0):

Use a function or make a script.

```
caps() python -c '
from ctypes import *
X11 = cdll.LoadLibrary("libX11.so.6")
display = X11.XOpenDisplay(None)
X11.XkbLockModifiers(display, c_uint(0x0100), c_uint(2), c_uint(0))
X11.XCloseDisplay(display)'
```