# Read non-bash variables from a file into bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, read

My bash script needs to read the variables from a text file that contains hundreds of variables, most of which conform to standard bash variable syntax (e.g., `VAR1=VALUE1`). However, a few lines in this file can be problematic, and I hope to find a simple solution to reading them into bash.

Here's what the file looks like:

```
#comment
VAR1=VALUE1
VAR_2=VALUE_2
...
VAR5=VALUE 5 (ASDF)
VAR6=VALUE 6 #a comment
VAR7=/path/with/slashes/and,commas
VAR8=2.1
VAR9=a name with spaces
VAR_10=true
...
VAR_N=VALUE_N
```

The rules about the file structure include:

- one variable (with value) per line
- the assignment (=) has no spaces around it
- the variable name is in the first column (unless it is a comment line)
- comments can follow the value (after #)
- the values can include spaces, parens, slashes, commas, and other chars
- the values can be floating point numbers (2.1), integers, true/false, or strings.
- string values are not quoted, and they can be a thousand chars long or longer
- the variable name contains only letters and underscores UPDATE: **and numbers**.

Most of the variables are of a type that would just allow me to source the file into my bash script. But those few problematic ones dictate a different solution. I'm not sure how to read them.

Comment: Can you just put the RHS into single quotes?

Comment: @Ketan - how do you mean? I can't change the text file with the variables.

Comment: You don't have to change the original text file, run it through sed and put the output in a new file and source it.

Comment: @Ketan - that sounds like it should work... can you provide an answer with example code? The devil is often in the details, especially with bash. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can transform this file to be a shell snippet, it's tricky. You need to make sure that all shell special characters are properly quoted.

The easiest way to do that is to [put single quotes around the value](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23347/wrapping-a-command-that-includes-single-and-double-quotes-for-another-command/23349#23349) and replace single quotes inside the value by `'\''`. You can then put the result into a temporary file and source that file.

```
script=$(mktemp)
sed <"config-file" >"$script" \
  -e '/^[A-Z_a-z][A-Z_a-z]*=/ !d' \
  -e s/\'/\'\\\\\'\'/g \
  -e s/=/=\'/ -e s/\$/\'/
```

I recommend doing the parsing directly in the shell instead. The complexity of the code is about the same, but there are two major benefits: you avoid the need for a temporary file, and the risk that you accidentally got the quoting wrong and end up executing a part of a line as a shell snippet (something like `dangerous='$(run me)'`). You also get a better chance at validating potential errors.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  line=${line%%#*}  # strip comment (if any)
  case $line in
    *=*)
      var=${line%%=*}
      case $var in
        *[!A-Z_a-z]*)
          echo "Warning: invalid variable name $var ignored" >&2
          continue;;
      esac
      if eval '[ -n "${'$var'+1}" ]'; then
        echo "Warning: variable $var already set, redefinition ignored" >&2
        continue
      fi
      line=${line#*=}
      eval $var='"$line"'
  esac
done <"config-file"
```

Comment: I'm using your recommended (2nd) method. Works great. Is there an easy way to check for a variable naming collision during this while-loop? With this approach it seems like that check might be appropriately incorporated.

Comment: Regarding name collisions, I guess I could use `eval IMPORTED_$var='"$line"'` but I would rather first check for collisions and not change/prefix the variable names.

Comment: @MountainX See my edit.

Comment: BTW, I made a mistake regarding the variable name convention. The standard letters, numbers and underscores are allowed. So the char class expression should be `[!A-Z_a-z0-9]`.

Comment: @Gilles-re: name collisions. I guess the principle of your solution is that null `+1` is still null. So if the result of that expression is not null, the variable name exists. Correct?

Comment: @MountainX `${foo+1}` expands to `1` if `foo` is set (to any value, including the empty string) and to the empty string if `foo` is unset.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your contents are in a file `x.txt`, you can use a `sed` expression:

```
sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/=.*$/="&"/g' -e 's/=//2' x.txt
```

First expression puts everything after the `=` sign in quotes. Second expression removes extra `=` sign and the third expression removes everything between `#` and `"` as they are comments.

Following will quote RHS into single quotes:

```
sed -e "s/#.*//" -e "s/=.*$/='&'/g" -e "s/=//2" x.txt
```

Comment: The result is VAR1"=value1"

Comment: Yep, realized that and made an update. See if it works now.

Comment: This doesn't handle values containing `"` or `'`.

Comment: It also handles comments incorrectly (the leading quote is kept, the trailing quote is deleted together with the #). BTW, it's probably useful to delete the comment together with any preceding whitespace.

Comment: @Gilles It does retain single and double quotes in the RHS. @Uwe I made changes to treat comments correctly. Everything after `#` is now removed first.

Comment: @Ketan So you'd be happy with parsing a file containing `do_not_run_this='$(rm -rf ~)'"$(rm -rf ~)"`? (DO NOT TRY THIS!)

Comment: @Gilles After putting the line you mentioned in the file along with other lines OP mentioned and running it through the sed expression I get the following for your line: `do_not_run_this=''$(rm -rf ~)'"$(rm -rf ~)"'`. Not sure how this is not what OP might have wanted.

Comment: This is definitely not what the OP wanted. The values are meant to be literal strings, not shell commands. If you try to parse the output as a shell script (which is what the question was about), this runs one of the `rm -rf ~` commands (either the first or the second, depending on which of your snippet he chooses). (ping @MountainX, by the way: seriously, DO NOT RUN THIS! It's a gaping security hole.)

Comment: @Gilles - thanks for all the discussion. I am reading and learning...